# Declaration or statement expected error in typescript file (angular2)

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to sum up the values entered in the `mat-table` column using an input.

I have created a table with 3 columns: `Account Id`, `Account Description` and `Value`. I have also created a JSON file in the assets folder with the values for `acc_id` and `acc_desc` .

I then access these values in my table for the respective columns.

I have also created a `Value` column for which i have assigned input field.

Next to the table i took a simple grid with two tiles where i want to take the sum of all the values entered in the `Value` column.

`account.component.html`

```html
    <!-- Table starts here -->

<mat-card>
<div class="example-container mat-elevation-z8">

  <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource1">

    <!-- Account No. Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="acc_id">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Account ID. </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.acc_id}}</mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

    <!-- Account Description Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="acc_des">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Account Description </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.acc_des }} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>

        <!-- Value Column -->
    <ng-container matColumnDef="value">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Value </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
     <ng-container>
       <input  [(ngModel)]="element.value">
     </ng-container> 
   </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>


    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns1" ></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns1;" > </mat-row>

  </mat-table>

   <mat-grid-list cols="2" rowHeight="20:1">

  <mat-grid-tile style="align-self: left;"> Total</mat-grid-tile>
  <mat-grid-tile>{{calculation()}}</mat-grid-tile>

</mat-grid-list>

</div>
</mat-card>
```

`account.component.ts`

```ts
import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import { ReactiveFormsModule, FormGroup,FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material';
import { AccountdetailService } from '../accountdetail.service';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-account',
  templateUrl: './account.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./account.component.scss']
   })


export class AccountComponent implements OnInit {

element: string;
value: any;
constructor( private accdetailservice: AccountdetailService ) { }


  /* Table Starts here
  ---------------------- */

 displayedColumns1 = ['acc_id', 'acc_des', 'value'];
 dataSource1= new MatTableDataSource<Element>(ELEMENT_DATA);


calculation(){ 
return this.dataSource1.data.reduce((summ, v) => summ += parseInt(v.value), 0) 
}



 ngOnInit(){
  this.accdetailservice.accountdetails().subscribe(data =>
  var tempObject = data.map(obj => ({...obj, value: 0}));
  this.dataSource1.data = tempObject; );
 }
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: Element[] = [];
```

`accountdetails.service.ts`

```ts
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';


@Injectable()
export class AccountdetailService {

  constructor(private http:Http ) { }

  accountdetails()
  {
    return this.http.get('/assets/accountdetails.json')
    .map(result => result.json());
  }}
```

`accountdetails.json`

```json
[
    {
        "acc_id": 1001,
        "acc_des": "aaa"

    },

    {
        "acc_id": 1002,
        "acc_des": "aaa"

    }
]
```

`app.module.ts`

```ts
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import { ReactiveFormsModule,FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule} from '@angular/http';

import { AppMaterialModule } from './app-material.module';


import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { AccountComponent } from './account/account.component';

import { AccountdetailService } from './accountdetail.service';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    AccountComponent    
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    AppMaterialModule,
    FormsModule ,
    HttpModule   
  ],
  entryComponents:[ ],

  providers: [ AccountdetailService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

I am able to sum up the values entered in the value column , but I am getting the below error .

[image]

can anybody tell me what is missing in my syntax in the following code...?

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.accdetailservice.accountdetails().subscribe(data =>
  var tempObject = data.map(obj => ({...obj, value: 0}));
  this.dataSource1.data = tempObject; );
 }
```

This is my output..

[image]

Comment: i tried as many ways out as i can ... but i am not getting rid of that error... despite my application is running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.accdetailservice.accountdetails().subscribe(data => {
     var tempObject = data.map(obj => ({...obj, value: 0}));
     this.dataSource1.data = tempObject; 
  });
}
```

Comment: but now I am getting an error for which previously i posted a question on this link ...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49044826/property-value-does-not-exist-on-type-element/49045031?noredirect=1#comment85100544_49045031

Comment: i.e. property value does not exist on type Element

Comment: I don t see in your code the interface Element. https://stackblitz.com/angular/qdyqleomobm?file=app%2Ftable-filtering-example.ts as you can see, you have to define the structure of Element

Comment: i just added..export interface Element {
  acc_id: any;
  value: any;
  acc_des: any;
}

Comment: can you please check this question...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49069432/assigning-the-required-value-for-mat-select-implemented-in-mat-table-in-angular?noredirect=1#comment85145320_49069432